# Super simple accessibility app for iPad/iPod Touch

Tags: itunes, ipad, software-recommendation, ipod-touch, accessibility

My mother is now visually impaired and I've got an old iPad which I want to turn into a "audiobook station" for her. However, with the vision problems, operating the Music App turns out to be impossible (also, she's 80+y/o and really not into tech). Also, accessibility options on the tablet were not enough.

I can take care of keeping the iPad online and feed with new books, but I wish she had at least the ability to play/pause the book at any given moment. For that, would be ideal if the screen were a big simple Play/Pause button she'd simply hit once.

Kind of like [Big Button Music Player](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/big-button-music-player/id354903233) but hopefully even simpler.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This list of apps is for the people with low vision or the blind.  There was blind guy I met that was using an app that used sound and voice when he moved his fingers across the iPad.

http://www.applevis.com/apps/ios-apps-for-blind-and-vision-impaired